Anchor cli 0.30.0 missing field 'discriminator'
I have a program which builds fine with anchor 0.29.0, with anchor 30 it does not build at all with the following error:
➜  avm use 0.30.0          
Now using anchor version 0.30.0.
➜  anchor build -p someprogram -- --features somefeature
Error: missing field `discriminator` at line 9 column 5

The same program will build with 0.29.0:
➜  avm use 0.29.0          
Now using anchor version 0.29.0.
➜  anchor build -p someprogram -- --features somefeature
 // builds as expected...

But since we have already upgraded to Anchor 30 and it is not backwards compatible, it can't build the IDL.

Please share an MRE

This was related to build artifacts from previous versions, anchor clean and deleting the target and .Anchor folders resolved the issue.
